# Which Rules Event should I use to trigger a Rules Action when accessing a particular Views page?

Tags: views, rules

I have a [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) page, located at, say, `www.example.com/entrepreneur`.

When a user accesses that particular url, I want some rule to be executed.

I've looked at the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) admininistration page to find out what exactly I should use as (the mandatory) "**React on event**", which looks like so:

[image]

But I am not able to find "**page is viewed**", but I need to execute the rule when user accesses the particular single page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download [Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) ,[Rule_link module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link) [Token module](https://www.drupal.org/project/token)

1. Enable Rule and Rule link and Token module
2. Go to /admin/config/workflow/rules_links
3. Add a new rule_link, Give the rule label and all other required field
4. Click on Configure rules tab and in access conditions you can add your conditions

Comment: Sorry @Yama, but the **Rules_Link** module is to "*create links which trigger arbitrary functionality with the help of Rules*" ... That is not at all what this question is about ... I think. Or am I missing something why you think this module does indeed help to answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) action that you want to trigger is to just set a Drupal message like "**Hi there ...**". But this action should only be triggered when "Viewing the content" located at a path like "`/entrepreneur`".

To get this to work, use the rule below (in Rules export format, just import it in your site and check the results of it):

```
{ "rules_visit_view_with_path_entrepreneur" : {
    "LABEL" : "Visit view with path entrepreneur",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-page:path" ], "value" : "/entrepreneur" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Hi there" } } ]
  }
}
```

The rule above should be close to what you're looking for, except maybe from these further refinements:

- Replace the ***Rules Action*** by your own "Rules Action" (which you didn't specify).
- This Rules Action will be performed **before** your content located at `/entrepreneur` is actually shown. That implies you could also issue some redirect (to another path) for whatever reason (so that the content located at some other URL would be shown **instead**.